# How to convert python modules like requests,pyfdt into executable formate and how to import this exe into another file

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, install.packages

i have file which should require some python packages like request,pyfdt,xlrd .i want to import these packages from know image instead of installing them

ex: main.py

## !/usr/bin/python

import requests,pyfdt,xlrd,pysmb
....
....
....
end of the code

is it possible to convert python modules to exe file ,i want to deliver that exe file along with main.py file so that user need not to install packages

Python 2.7.3  on linux

Comment: Same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency